# Declare variable one time global or several times local?

Tags: c#, class, variables, methods

Im currently just thinking what is better.
I have functions that are called very often that use variables that just these functions are using, and Im thinking if I should declare them once as global in the class so I can always reuse them in the function. Or declare them in the method and therefor each time the function is executed.
How would that be done professionally?

Comment: There's no one-size-fits-all solution here, so it depends on the situation. Do you use the variables in just one method? If yes, it is probably a good idea to define them locally.

Comment: Don't describe code. Show code.

Comment: There's nothing wrong as declaring them as private to the class. If they're used in multiple methods, that's the way to go. That's if I understood your context correctly. Just show an example of all the ways you thought about.

Comment: Think of scope, reusability, and minimal coding. If creating a global variable fits the mold, then do it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should declare the variables in the smallest scope that needs to use it. That reduces the risk that the wrong variable is used in the wrong place. Making the code robust and maintainable should always be the first concern. It doesn't matter how fast the code is, if it doesn't work properly.

Anyhow, declaring local variables is very cheap. When the method is called a stack frame is created on the stack, and space for local variables is made by making the stack frame larger. As setting the size of the stack frame is just an instruction that does a subtraction on the stack pointer, and that is done anyway, it literally takes no time at all to allocate the space for local variables.

Comment: Of course this only addresses the "allocating storage" part of variable creation.  If the initialization is expensive, it's perfectly reasonable to keep those results instead of throwing them away and repeating the initialization.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Yes, but then it's not a matter of reusing a variable, but reusing a value.

Comment: Well, reusing an object.  Both the location and the content.  In many cases the semantic value isn't being reused, while the implementation content is.  For example, database connection pools or thread pools.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is, it depends. If you are setting these variables at one place and ONLY reading values from them in functions in question then making them global makes sense but if you intend to modify them in these functions then your functions wont produce expected result if you make them global.
Global variables behaves like singleton so you need to be cautious with global variables.